# Two Independent Axis Barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a barplot that was two independent Y axis, as a way to lookup the count of contratcs and the amount value of the count on PowerBi.

x axis - Year/Month timeline
y axis - Amount of Contracts Values
y2 axis - Count of Contracts

The point is that the graph must be done as barplot and I have to show it on PowerBi. But PowerBi don't offer a bar/bar plot type in their visuals, just bar/line thats it's not cool to use for what I need.

I found a way to do the graph using a private visual from xViz but I'm also trying to on R Studio to put inside the PowerBi later.

In the end the graph should be like that:

[image]

I tryed to use ggplot2 with sec.axis() but in that way the second axis works as a transformation of the first as:

```
data_long <- melt(data)
plot <- ggplot(data_long,aes(Group.1,value,fill = variable)) + 
geom_col(,position = "dodge")+
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100000, name="Contracts"))
```

the problem is that the number of contracts are very small relation of the amount value of then, what makes the graph on R been shown like that:

[image]

Can someone help me with that issue?

Comment: You also have to scale your data, ie. do something like `data_long$value  <- ifelse(data_long$variable == "Clientes", data_long$value * 100000, data_long$value)`.

Comment: @stefan, it's not going to make me lose the true value when but the labels on the columns?

Comment: Sure. But that's the way to go if you want a secondary scale, i.e. you have to fix that by dividing for the labels too. Second option. Add a new column with the scaled values which you can map on y, while for the labels you use the raw values.

Comment: Cool, I've made the second column with value_column and it's works ;)!!

Thankss!